# Python Schedule - Execute at the time of server starting

Tags: python, pip, scheduled-tasks, schedule

I need to execute a task.
i want to delete a table details at the interval of 30 days.
and i want to execute the task  automatically while our server starts(after executing python manage.py runserver)

then i tried
pip install schedule

my scheduler function

```
def set_timeschedule():
   HeartBeatLog.objects.all().delete()
```

then i dont understand i call the function

so i called this in urls.py

```
if date.today().day == 28:
  schedule.every().day.at("16:36").do(set_timeschedule)
```

time  added for testing ( i need to execute them in 30 days gap)
here HeartBeatLog is my modal. and i cant get this in manage.py or urls.py

but its not working

1. Is this is the Proper way for doing task ?
2. How can i get the Exact data.
3. where i put this code to delete the data while staring the server.
4. is it possible to kill the schedule after 1 time execution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it up as such:

```
def set_timeschedule():
    if date.today().day == 28:
        HeartBeatLog.objects.all().delete()

schedule.every().day.at("16:36").do(set_timeschedule) # Sets up a job

while True:
    schedule.run_pending() # Checks for active jobs and runs
    sleep(900) # Sleep for 900s
```

You need to have run_pending() for the jobs that are scheduled to run

Comment: hi @cyneo in which file i need to write this ?  i want to execute this  while python manage.py run server starts

Comment: sounds like you want it in manage.py. Note that this means that instance will have to keep running indefinitely. I personally add a print statement before sleep(900) so I would know if the instance has stopped for any reason.

Comment: ok...   HeartBeatLog  is my model , but i cant access it in manage.py or urls.py

Comment: The key is that you need to call schedule.run_pending() for it to run, otherwise you are just queuing up jobs and not running them. Sorry but I can't really advise much on how you want to restructure the example function. =)

Comment: Yes, but it also means you can write the function to do it once, and just bypass all the effort of using schedule module =)